# Inserting a plain TextView between CollapsingToolbarLayout and RecyclerView

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to make an app which has a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` followed by a `RecyclerView` containing several cardviews.

I want to insert a plain `TextView` between the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `RecyclerView` but i was unable to do it. I tried many things but it gives buggy results.

**Here is the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

          <RelativeLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.co nbm/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#ffffff">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="MEET THE PEOPLE WHO CHANGED THE WORLD"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/textView2"
                  android:text="It is an art 100% and I am an artist 100%.It is here where is my happiness"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"
                  android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
                  android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
                  android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
                  android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/textView3"
                  android:text="-VIKI GÒMEZ"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="-280dp"
                  android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
                  android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
                  android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
                  android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="24sp"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
         </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should not work, of course.currently, `RecyclerView` is under the `AppBarLayout`.

**With the following code:**

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

So, you were doing that on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and you said that:

> Inserting a plain textview **between Collapsing toolbar and recyclerview**

So, that is one problem.and another thing is, That `RecyclerView` is scrollable.you should add the `TextViews` on the `NestedScrollView` (for scrolling it).

But another thing is, both of them are scrollable :) and that should not work.

**That should be like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MEET THE PEOPLE WHO CHANGED THE WORLD"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've added to the `RecyclerView`: `android:layout_marginTop="50dp"`.
and that should work.

**Proof:**

[image]

Comment: doesn't work......the textview gets stuck at the bottom of the screen and the scroll of the recyclerview overlaps the collapsing toolbar :(

Comment: Try to add it outside of nestedscrollview something like above the recyclerview and let me know.

Comment: actually i solved the problem.....I used the recyclerview to generate another cardview....

Comment: You may want to suggest an edit to my answer ;) because i explained the problem